# LIKE operator to load taxonomy term

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I want to retrieve a taxonomy term using this line:

```
$term = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
        ->loadByProperties(['myfield' => 'mytext']);
```

How can I rather use the 'LIKE' operator we have in SQL, so that in case the 'myfield' contains a text and not a string in the database, it still works?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer..I had to use the entity query then load term:

```
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
        ->condition('myfield', 'mytext', 'LIKE')
        ->execute();

$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
        ->loadMultiple($result);
```